# Jenkins pipeline - global (non-environment) attributes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am currently developing a rather complex scripted pipeline in Jenkins and there are some values which I need all along the build job. I have tried saving them into environment variables, e.g. `env.MY_VAR = 'foo'`.

However, this is limited to scalar values, and I need to store some structured data too, mainly small lists and maps. I know I could serialize/deserialize them as needed, but I don't want to.

Is there any (better) way to achieve this, other than using global variables? Do Jenkins objects provide any means to do something like `currentBuild.myCustomVars.add('myVar','foo')`?

Comment: So you don’t want to use global groovy variables? Like a=1?

Answer (score 0):

A better way might be to use a shared library to achieve that (see ["Extending with Shared Libraries"](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/). For example you could simply wrap a `Map` in `MyMap` put it in a shared lib and import it to your pipeline like this:

```
@Library('somelib')
import com.mycorp.pipeline.complextypes.MyMap
```

This is kind of complicated and I'd personally rather get rid of the complex types or use global variables, but if you need some more than simply a generic `Map` it might be worth the effort.